# What enzyme or bacteria could dissolve plastic?

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology, bacteriology, metabolism, enzymes

What enzyme or bacteria could dissolve plastic aside from acetone? Preferably, low-cost and environmentally friendly. Any suggestions would be helpful.

I'm targeting for thin plastic (low-density polyethylene). Environmentally friendly for me is that it follows the EPA standards from the USA. I'm targeting for around 150 USD. I'm okay with solvents that make the plastic swell, but a chemical that could dissolve it is preferable.

I asked this on the ChemStack Exchange and I'm not sure if enzymes and bacteria are allowed there so I'm asking here too. Thank you!

Comment: You should wait before the [chemistry.se] people decide that it is off topic there before posting to another SE. Don't simultaneously post on multiple websites. If it is indeed off topic there, they can migrate the question here.

Comment: Anyway, did you try searching google scholar on this topic?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but I found out that Ideonella sakaiensis works, but it digests plastics in 6 weeks. I'm trying to find a more effective way to digest bacteria. Thanks!

Comment: @JosephLopez You should include prior research in your question. It would be kind of rude if someone wrote up a whole answer about *Ideonella sakaiensis* and then you responded "yeah but that takes a long time I'm looking for something better." However, you should also note it seems you are asking for a bit of a holy grail here: an EPA friendly way to quickly deal with one of the biggest pollution challenges of today? Sounds like a Nobel prize, not a SE answer.

Comment: Not an enzyme, but [D-limonen](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18072821) does a good job dissolving polystyrene. See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6b7GZQNFDbU) for example. It's cheap, and I assume about as environmentally friendly as dissolving plastic can be.

Comment: Thanks! Looking into it now with fresh eyes, my tone sounds kind of rude.... Thanks for correcting me! @BryanKrause

Comment: Thanks @theforestecologist for the suggestion!